# error in numpy : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'

Tags: python, numpy

Code:

```
self.r = np.array((x, y))    
self.radius = radius
def overlaps(self, other):
        """Does the circle of this Particle overlap that of other?"""

        return np.hypot(self.r , other.r) < self.radius + other.radius
```

I need to compare whether two circles coincide or not in a simulation code. and all i am getting is an error : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'

radius hold the information -

```
        def r_gen1(n1, radius1):
            for i in range(n1):
                yield radius1
```

Here is the complete code:

class Particle1:

```
def __init__(self, x, y, vx, vy, typ, radius=0.01, styles=None):
    """Initialize the particle's position, velocity, and radius.

    Any key-value pairs passed in the styles dictionary will be passed
    as arguments to Matplotlib's Circle patch constructor.

    """

    self.r = np.array((x, y))
    self.v = np.array((vx, vy))
    typ = 1
    self.radius = radius

    self.styles = styles
    if not self.styles:
        # Default circle styles
        self.styles = {'edgecolor': 'b', 'fill': False}

# For convenience, map the components of the particle's position and
# velocity vector onto the attributes x, y, vx and vy.
@property
def x(self):
    return self.r[0]
@x.setter
def x(self, value):
    self.r[0] = value
@property
def y(self):
    return self.r[1]
@y.setter
def y(self, value):
    self.r[1] = value
@property
def vx(self):
    return self.v[0]
@vx.setter
def vx(self, value):
    self.v[0] = value
@property
def vy(self):
    return self.v[1]
@vy.setter
def vy(self, value):
    self.v[1] = value

def overlaps(self, other):
    """Does the circle of this Particle overlap that of other?"""

    return np.hypot(self.r , other.r) < self.radius + other.radius

def draw(self, ax):
    """Add this Particle's Circle patch to the Matplotlib Axes ax."""

    circle = Circle(xy=self.r, radius=self.radius, **self.styles)
    ax.add_patch(circle)
    return circle

def advance(self, dt):

    self.r += self.v * dt

    # Make the Particles bounce off the walls
    if self.x - self.radius < 0:
        self.x = self.radius
        self.vx = -self.vx
    if self.x + self.radius > 1:
        self.x = 1-self.radius
        self.vx = -self.vx
    if self.y - self.radius < 0:
        self.y = self.radius
        self.vy = -self.vy
    if self.y + self.radius > 1:
        self.y = 1-self.radius
        self.vy = -self.vy
```

there are 3 such particle classes.
class Simulation:

```
def __init__(self, n1,n2,n3, radius1=0.01, radius2 = 0.01, radius3 = 0.01, styles1=None, styles2 = None, styles3 = None):

    self.init_particles(n1,n2,n3, radius1,radius2, radius3, styles1, styles2, styles3)

def init_particles(self, n1,n2,n3, radius1,radius2,radius3, styles1=None, styles2 = None, styles3 = None):

    try:
        iterator1 = iter(radius1)
        assert n1 == len(radius1)
        iterator2 = iter(radius2)
        assert n2 == len(radius2)
        iterator3 = iter(radius3)
        assert n3 == len(radius3)
    except TypeError:
        def r_gen1(n1, radius1):
            for i in range(n1):
                yield radius1
        radius1 = r_gen1(n1, radius1)
        def r_gen2(n2,radius2):
          for i in range(n2):
            yield radius2
        radius2 = r_gen2(n2,radius2)
        def r_gen3(n3,radius3):
          for i in range(n3):
            yield radius3
        radius3 = r_gen3(n3,radius3)

    self.n1 = n1
    self.n2 = n2
    self.n3 = n3

    self.particles1 = []
    self.particles2 = []
    self.particles3 = []

    for i, rad in enumerate(radius1):
        while True:
            x, y = rad + (1 - 2*rad) * np.random.random(2)
            vr = 0.1 * np.random.random() + 0.05
            vphi = 2*np.pi * np.random.random()
            vx, vy = vr * np.cos(vphi), vr * np.sin(vphi)
            particle1 = Particle1(x, y, vx, vy, rad, styles)

            for p2 in self.particles1:
                if p2.overlaps(particle1):
                    break
            else:
                self.particles1.append(particle1)
                break

    for i, rad in enumerate(radius2):
        while True:
            x, y = rad + (1 - 2*rad) * np.random.random(2)
            vr = 0.1 * np.random.random() + 0.05
            vphi = 2*np.pi * np.random.random()
            vx, vy = vr * np.cos(vphi), vr * np.sin(vphi)
            particle2 = Particle2(x, y, vx, vy, rad, styles)

            for p2 in self.particles2:
                if p2.overlaps(particle2):
                    break
            else:
                self.particles2.append(particle2)
                break

    for i, rad in enumerate(radius3):
        while True:
            x, y = rad + (1 - 2*rad) * np.random.random(2)
            vr = 0.1 * np.random.random() + 0.05
            vphi = 2*np.pi * np.random.random()
            vx, vy = vr * np.cos(vphi), vr * np.sin(vphi)
            particle3 = Particle3(x, y, vx, vy, rad, styles)

            for p2 in self.particles3:
                if p2.overlaps(particle3):
                    break
            else:
                self.particles3.append(particle3)
                break


def handle_collisions(self):

    def change_velocities(p1, p2):

        m1, m2 = p1.radius**2, p2.radius**2
        M = m1 + m2
        r1, r2 = p1.r, p2.r
        d = np.linalg.norm(r1 - r2)**2
        v1, v2 = p1.v, p2.v
        u1 = v1 - 2*m2 / M * np.dot(v1-v2, r1-r2) / d * (r1 - r2)
        u2 = v2 - 2*m1 / M * np.dot(v2-v1, r2-r1) / d * (r2 - r1)
        p1.v = u1
        p2.v = u2

    pairs = combinations(range(self.n), 2)
    for i,j in pairs:
        if self.particles1[i].overlaps(self.particles1[j]):
            change_velocities(self.particles1[i], self.particles1[j])

def advance_animation(self, dt):

    for i, p in enumerate(self.particles1):
        p.advance(dt)
        self.circles[i].center = p.r
    self.handle_collisions()
    return self.circles

def advance(self, dt):
    for i, p in enumerate(self.particles1):
        p.advance(dt)
    self.handle_collisions()

def init(self):
    self.circles = []
    for particle in self.particles1:
        self.circles.append(particle.draw(self.ax))
    return self.circles

def animate(self, i):
    self.advance_animation(0.01)
    return self.circles

def do_animation(self, save=False):
    fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
    for s in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
        self.ax.spines[s].set_linewidth(2)
    self.ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
    self.ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
    self.ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
    self.ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
    self.ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, self.animate, init_func=self.init,
                           frames=800, interval=2, blit=True)
    if save:
        Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
        writer = Writer(fps=100, bitrate=1800)
        anim.save('collision.mp4', writer=writer)
    else:
        plt.show()
```

Comment: can you share the data which variable radius holds? Error says you are adding twio dictionaries

Comment: Edited. @Neeraj

Comment: You need to trace the source of the `self.radius` and figure out why it is a `dict` rather than a number.  I see too many 'radius' to readily do that.  If it is your code, make sure you know what every variable is at every time.  Don't guess, test and know.

Comment: @hpaulj the thing is, radius needs a dict value - since a 'n' elements are being generated together in the simulation.

Comment: Regardless, you can't use '+' with a `dict`.  It isn't defined for `dict` objects.